# Update work-item state using enum or create specific methods for updating work-item state

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

Statement:

There are two choices:

WorkItemState is an emum and can be : SCHEDULED, READY, SUBMITTED, EXECUTING, COMPLETED

1. Create single method : updateWorkItemState(workItemId, workItemState)
2. Create multiple methods : markAsCompleted(workItemId), markAsSubmitted(workItemId), markAsExecuting(workItemId) etc.

In first approach, I am exposing work item states to client while in second approach I have to create multiple methods i.e one for each state.

I also have to check that state transition can be applied only if current state is valid. Ex- If work item is in EXECUTING state, then only it can be completed.

Which of the two approach seems better in terms of readability, maintainability and extensibility?

Comment: Why not both?  Make the first item's (1) private/protected, then make the second (2) methods call the private/protected method to handle the actual work.  This is best for reusability and readability.

Comment: True. If I go with second apporach, I already thought I will be writing code in this manner, but the question is whether to go with second or not. As states keep increasing, methods will also start increasing.

Answer (score 0):

It's subjective, I would prefer the second approach.

The first approach is more generic, less code, easy to write and understand and has just one function to test.
I would say it violates S of SOLID principles.
Each status will ask you to perform different tasks and in no time this will become complicated.
The test case though just one function, will have numerous scenarios to test for just one function.

The second approach allows you to have an abstracted method for the consumer which performs a single task.
Code will be short and tidy for each method.
Though it has more functions to test, it's easy and more clear as to what you are testing.

Also, if you want to update logic later for one of the status, you know where to change and would not be breaking/retesting anything else.

Anyways even in first one when it grows you will end up dividing it into private functions. It's better to give easy interfaces to the consumer and not expose your status. Gives more flexibility.

Comment: Do let me know your thoughts, we all are always learning on this platform.